# struggling to link f90 subroutine with c program

Tags: gcc, cmake, fortran, linker-errors, gfortran

Simple program

main.C

```
#include <iostream>
void sub3();

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello from C World\n";
        sub2();
    sub3();
    return(0);
}
void sub2(){
    std::cout << "Sub1\n";
    return;
}
```

and sub3.f90

```
    subroutine sub3() 
    write(*,*) 'Hello from F90 sub3'
    return
    end
```

Using Ubuntu,

gfortran -c -fno-underscoring sub3.f90

is supposed to prevent the name mangling with an appended underscore

gcc (or g++) main.C -c

linking with either gfortran or gcc using combinations of -lgfortran -lsdtc++

Cannot find combination to have sub3 Or sub3() as defined reference.

Preferably was CMake to work, also

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(ProjName VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES  C CXX Fortran)
include(FortranCInterface)

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lgfortran")
set( CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -lstdc++ -fno-underscoring")
set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}  )
add_library(ProjFLib sub3.f90 )
add_executable( ProjTest  main.C  )
target_link_libraries( ProjTest  ProjFLib )
```

Whether appended (or suppressed) underscore, cannot get combination to link, with some iterations having undefined reference to throw_*length_*errror , operator delete(), ...

Comment: Welcome, please always show the exact error messages that you are getting. See [ask].

Answer (score 3):

A few minor fixes and improvements to make it work:

- You need to disable the C++ name mangling by putting the prototype inside an `extern "C"` block.
- To avoid relying on non-standard Fortran compiler options to disable the Fortran name mangling, use the `bind(C)` feature.
- I had to put `sub2()` before `main()`, otherwise the compiler complained about a missing declaration. (Or writing a prototype would also have worked.)

Thus, main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    void sub3();
}

void sub2(){
    std::cout << "Sub1\n";
    return;
}
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello from C World\n";
    sub2();
    sub3();
    return(0);
}
```

sub3.f90:

```
subroutine sub3() bind(C, name="sub3") 
    write(*,*) 'Hello from F90 sub3'
    return
end
```

To compile and run:

```
$ gfortran -O2 -Wall -c sub3.f90
$ g++ -O2 -Wall main.cpp sub3.o -lgfortran
$ ./a.out 
Hello from C World
Sub1
 Hello from F90 sub3
```